# Read a string of alphanumeric characters after a ;

Tags: perl, scripting

I'm teaching myself perl so I'm pretty new to this language. I've been reading over and over about regular expression but I can't figure out the right context. I want to do the following:

Let say I have a file name "testfile" 
 this files contains 3 lines,

```
test this is the first line
test: this is the first line
test; this is the third line
```

How can I read and print out only the third one and everything after the `;` without the space. so basically "This is the third line"

This is what I'm thinking to do `$string =~ m/this is the third/`

This was edited incorrectly. In the first and second sentence there should a space before the test.in the third one shouldn't. So I want to skip the white space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grabbing from STDIN, it might look like this:

```
while ( <> ) { 
   print $1 if /^test; (.*\n)/;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the third line, then simply counting the lines and then doing:

```
s/.*;\s*//;
```

will remove everything until the ; and any white space after it.  Note, however, that if the third line contains another ';' in it then you'll be in trouble.  So if that's a possibility but there is no chance that one will exist earlier, then do this:

```
s/[^;]*;\s*//;
```

Which will delete only up until the first ';' (and trailing whitespace).

I suspect, however, in the long run you want to match all lines that contain some particular format and it won't always be "just the third".  If that's the case then:

```
while(<>) {
   if (/;\s*(.*)/) {
       print $1;
   }
}
```

Will get you closer to your end-goal.

Comment: This is an excellent Answer. Sorry, I'm very very new to Perl. could you please explain me every character here s/[^;]*;\s*//;

Comment: There is no need for the negated character class. `/;\s*(.*)/` will work fine. @Wes: this means to find a semicolon followed by zero or more whitespace characters and capture everything following.

Comment: @NewLearner: [^;]* means "match everything except a `;` character as many times as possible (with no minimum, so matching 0 works).  The `;` means "find a `;`".  And the \s* means "find as much white space as possible after it, with a minimum count of 0".

Comment: This works for me as a simple test of the above: `echo "test; this is the third line" | perl -p -e 's/[^;]*;\s*//;'`

Answer (score 1):

You might find that [YAPE::Regex::Explain](http://search.cpan.org/~gsullivan/YAPE-Regex-Explain-4.01/) is a handy tool:

Using Axeman's regular expression:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use YAPE::Regex::Explain;
my $expr = q(/^test; (.*\n)/);
print YAPE::Regex::Explain->new( $expr )->explain;

The regular expression:

(?-imsx:/^test; (.*\n)/)

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  /                        '/'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  test;                    'test; '
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \n                       '\n' (newline)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  /                        '/'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve this is to try to remove everything up to the first `;` (and any spaces straight afterwards), and only print the line if there was something to remove.

```
s/.*?;\s*//;
```

This line basically says: "match any characters (but as few as possible), then a semicolon, then any spaces, and replace it all with nothing".

You can then make a the program that reads from STDIN:

```
while (<>) {
  print if s/.*?;\s*//;
}
```

You can turn these into a nice one-liner on the command line too:

```
perl -ne 'print if s/.*?;\s*//;'
```